# Xcode 7.1 UI Testing and Code Coverage

Tags: ios, xcode7, xcode-ui-testing

I've noticed that my Xcode 7.1 code coverage results see to be unaffected by any UI tests I've written.  I can set a break point to make sure a particular line of code is hit during a UI test, but the coverage statistics don't reflect it properly.

I read in some of the 'beta' notes for Xcode 7.0 that Code Coverage was supposed to extend to UI Testing?  Did that get dropped, or is there a setting I'm missing?

Comment: I have the same problem when I run my tests individually. But when I run all test (cmd+U), the code coverage is working well.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Using XCUITest framework for UI tests, but after running various XCTestCase's successfully, the code coverage reported by XCode server is 0%. Is this not supported for UI tests yet?

Answer (score 1):

You need to Turn on code coverage in the scheme editor for a target.
https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/tvos/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/Xcode_Overview/CheckingCodeCoverage.html

Comment: For me, this doesn't solve it. I get coverage for Unit Tests, but not UI Tests.

Comment: Make sure you've checked "Debug Executable" switch in Scheme Settings